# How can I distinguish a Canon IIS2 from a Canon IID2?

Tags: canon, rangefinder

I have come into possession of a Canon rangefinder but I'm not sure what model it is. On the basis of various clues, including the shutter speeds available and the serial number, I know it is either a IIS2 or a IID2, but I can't tell which one. Is there some way to distinguish between these two?

Comment: Google "Pacific Rim Camera" as they have an excellent article describing the differences in the Canon rangefinder cameras. One of the answers has cut and pasted a portion of PRC's work. This is how I discovered the identity of my IIS2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this page](http://www.pacificrimcamera.com/pp/canon/ii.htm), the IID2 has no flash capacity, while the IIS2 does.

Quoting:

> The IID2, like the rest of the IID line has no flash capacity. Built
>   through 1956, production was slightly over 16,000 units.
>
> Like the IIF, the IIF2 has flash provision for bulbs only, the slow
>   speed dial has no X on it. Unlike the IIF, this was a low production
>   camera (2625), and was discontinued in Nov of 1955.
>
> The IIS2, if you haven't already figured it out, has all of the
>   features of the IIF2, but it also has an x-sych for electronic flash,
>   marked on the slow spped dial. This was a popular model, with
>   production of over 16,000 units, and discontinued in 1956.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I understand the functional difference, but is there some way to distinguish them by looking? From photographs, these cameras look identical. How would I be able to distinguish these from each other, and from the IIF2, which also looks the same? Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelStern The flash capacity should have a visual difference.  Either there is a way to hook up a flash bulb or there isn't.

Comment: The "way to hook up a flash", by the way, is an accessory rail on the left-hand side of the camera body, below the strap lug. You won't find a PC terminal or a hot shoe.

Comment: Ah! I was looking only at the top of the camera. The accessory rail had escaped me. Looks like I have a IIS2 and a IIF2.  Thank you.